# How to check if MACD value is Negative or Positive?

Tags: mql4, mql

I am using `iMACD(NULL, PERIOD_CURRENT, 12, 26, 9, PRICE_CLOSE, MODE_MAIN, i)` function to get an MACD value but it returns fraction number, like **`0.154154`** or **`-0.154549`**, so I need to check if the MACD value is positive or negative.

How do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *How to check if MACD value is Negative or Positive?*

Using the returned value, just test it like this:

```
if ( 0 > iMACD( _Symbol, PERIOD_CURRENT, 12, 26, 9, PRICE_CLOSE, MODE_MAIN, i )
{ // NEGATIVE
     ...
  }
else
{ // NON-NEGATIVE
     ...
  }
```